# import another css file in QT stylesheet

Tags: css, qt, import, stylesheet

I have QT version 4.5.3. Does it support @import()? I'm trying to import another css file into my css file I have cssA.css and cssB.css in the same folder. I import cssA.css in cssB.css by using @import(:/cssA.css); but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a good answer myself, so I manually concatenate multiple stylesheets to emulate 'importing'. For example, in C++:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
// Load stylesheets
QString finalCss;
QFile baseCssFile(":/Common/Theme.css");
if (baseCssFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    finalCss.append(baseCssFile.readAll().data());
}
QFile cssFile(":/CustomApp/CustomApp.css");
if (cssFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    finalCss.append(cssFile.readAll().data());
}
a.setStyleSheet(finalCss);
```

Comment: This is the only sane approach. Since [Qt currently provides *no* support for importing one stylesheet into another](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2047), the onus is squarely on developers to manually do so. `</forlorn_sigh>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try @import 'color_controls.css';

Comment: **QSS ≠ CSS.** Sadly, Qt provides *no* support for importing one stylesheet into another. See [this open Qt feature request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2047) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise taking a look at this website: [Stylesheets](http://apidocs.meego.com/1.1/platform/html/libmeegotouch/styling_stylesheets.html)

Syntax: @import ""; or @import url("");

For example:

```
@import "commonstylesheet.css";
```

Comment: **QSS ≠ CSS.** Sadly, Qt provides *no* support for importing one stylesheet into another. See [this open Qt feature request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2047) for further discussion.